# Quickest way to uncheck 'Same As Billing' when any shipping field is changed

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a fieldset for BillingInfo and a 2nd fieldset within the same form (hidden by default) where fields are mapped like so:

```
Billingfieldset
  FirstName
  LastName
  ...

Shippingfieldset
  ShippingFirstName
  ShippingLastName
  ...
```

Default when the page loads to have the 'SameAsBilling' checkbox :checked and all fields populated as per Billing fields. I want jQuery to uncheck that box as soon as the user begin typing a new value in any of the Shipping fields.

I'd like to avoid a long 'if / then' test that manually steps thru all the fields' :changed events but since there isn't a one-to-one mapping between the fieldsets perhaps that's not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $shippingFields = $('#Shippingfieldset').find('input').on('keyup', function()
{
    $('#sameAsCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
    $shippingFields.off();
});
```

Comment: using .on tossed a syntax error. I found that .click works. thx var $shippingFields = $('#shipFields').find('input').click(function () {

Comment: @justSteve - `.on()` was introduced in jQuery 1.7 - so if you're using anything below that you'll have to replace it with `.bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution:**

1. Place a class to all needed fields (eg. .shipping)
2. Place a a class on the SameAsBilling field (eg. .sameasbilling)
3. Use a selector like this:

   ```
   // Catch keydown
   $('.shipping').live('keydown','uncheckBox');

   // Uncheck box
   function uncheckBox() {
      $('.sameasbilling').removeAttr('checked');
   };
   ```